# Bluetooth is not working on Lenovo IdeaPad Y560p

Tags: bluetooth, lenovo, ideapad

I'm not sure how to get it working, Google didn't suggest any relevant information.
`rfkill list` shows a wifi device only, no bluetooth.

```
# rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I've posted a bug-report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1802077

Comment: After looking at the logs included with the bug report, I would say you have no bluetooth device connected.  Bluetooth is an option with most wifi cards

Comment: Jeremy31, thanks for your response. I've changed motherboard long ago, but previously bluetooth used to work with Windows. It seems like wifi card is separate from motherboard, but I'm not sure. How do I find out if Bluetooth device is present or not, to make the final conclusion? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing, and very simple thing, I had done to make my Bluetooth work in all aspects, was when 1 hour ago I was in utter frustration ans realized that just because I BOOTED from usb with my Ubuntu Studio ISO, didn't mean I was not still in Windows bios on the Lenovo IdeaPad. I restarted the IdeaPad, pressed fn f2, maybe f1 if not, and that put me in Bios mode. Then went to exit and down to windows os and switch it to OTHER OS. I saw this on a different site for unrelated just booting up video but it is Extremely important. Give it a check, not just you but tons of others with this problem. Bluetooth for me now works flawless on Ubuntu Studio... Newest version. Sorry number slips me. Maybe someone will detail this explanation a bit better what I did. Thank and love Ubuntu Studio. tony_

Comment: Suggestion: Consider to explain step by step and make use of list format. A wall of text is rather difficult to notice what you are trying to explain here.

Comment: It was apparently my kernel needing update from 4.15 to 4.20. just restarted the

Comment: Sorry you can delete my reply. It was a kernel issue. Needs 4.20 instead of my 4.15 it came with on Bionic Beaver.